# Pandas - iterate through dataframe and join if any element of a list matches any element of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, element

I have two series, and every cell of both series contains a list of elements of random length. My goal is to perform a cross-join between these two series, but only join rows if at least one element of a series' cell's list matches an element of a cell's list in the other series.

For example:

```
series_a

0   [1geor, georg, eorge, orges, rgesq, gesqu, esq...
1   [1mark, marks, arksq, rksqu, ksqua, squar, qua...
2   [1prim, primr, rimro, imros, mrose, roses, ose...
3   [1shan, shank, hanka, ankar, nkars, karst, wew...
4   [1stka, stkat, tkath, katha, athar, thari, har...

series_b

0   [115br, 15bro, 5broa, broad, roadw, oadwa, adway]
1   [11par, 1park, parkp, arkpl, rkpla, kplac, place]
2   [125we, 25wes, 5west, west2, est25, st25t, t25th]
3   [135ma, 35mad, 5madi, madis, adiso, dison]
4   [135we, 35wes, 5west, west4, est41]
```

I want to check, for every row in series_a, if at least one element in a row = an element in a row of series_b, and if yes, join those rows together in a new dataframe.

So, looking at series_a's first row, checking if '1geor' exists in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd. etc. list of series_b; if TRUE, perform the join, and if FALSE, do not perform the join.

To clarify, the returned dataframe should have two columns, where the first column contains cells from series_a and the second column contains cells from series_b. For all rows in this dataframe, the list in the 1st column should have at least one element that can be found in the list of the 2nd column. For example:

```
returned_df

0   [115br, 15bro, 5broa]                             | [15bro, abcde, 12345, hello, world, test1]
1   [11par, 1park, parkp, arkpl, rkpla]               | [parkp, broad]
2   [125we, 25wes, 5west, west2, est25, st25t, t25th] | [t25th, sadlf, 234lgk]
...
```

If an element in a row in series_a occurs in more than one row in series_b, all combinations of matching rows should appear in the final dataframe.

What is the most efficient Python code for this exercise? The code:

```
any(elem in b for elem in a)
```

easily answers this for two specific lists, but I want to iterate through both series in their entirety.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean `join`? So, if `1geor` is in *some* row in `series_b`, what do you want to do next?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This requires more effort to make clear.  I don't speak for everyone, but I wouldn't want to spend my time guessing at what you mean only to get it wrong.

Comment: Edited the question to make more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *list comprehension* once you have `object` dtypes in your series, and `pandas` string methods and iterative methods are very slow.

```
elements = [(item, elem) for item in series_a.tolist()\
                         for elem in series_b.tolist()\
            if bool(set(item).intersection(elem))]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(elements)
```